# NISTIR 7966 (Security of Automated Access Management Using Secure Shell) - is there anything new?

Tags: ssh, key-management

Tatu Ylönen (the creator of SSH protocol) and two others authored a [report](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/nistir-7966/nistir_7966_draft.pdf) recently, offering their views on SSH key management. I **have** read the report, and am struggling to identify whether it is corporate astroturfing for the authors' outfits or genuine advice to IT orgs using SSH widely and on a regular basis.

In particular, what are the advantages that a separate SSH key management system would provide for an enterprise network, and do they outweigh the costs and risk of single-point compromise of the said key provisioning/management system?

Comment: That's interesting, it seems like they're trying to use SSH in a PKI type of way.  Seems weird with SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Yolen described his motivation with existing examples in presentaion of LISA 2013, "Managing Access Using SSH Keys". https://www.usenix.org/conference/lisa13/managing-access-using-ssh-keys https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/ylonen_lisa13_slides.pdf

In the presentation as well as NISTIR 7966, they don't mentioned separate management system SHOULD be necessary. They just said lack of management frameworks introduce the risk. They give the "typical" case that have very large number of clients, servers, users and keys where management tools must be necessary. In general cases, risk and cost is just trade-off.  Many can keep ssh management without single-point system.